# Is this an example of recursion? I wanted to create a program that calculates the area of a rectangle using recursion

Tags: python

I wanted to create a program that calculates the area of a rectangle using recursion

```
def AreaofRectangle(width, height):
    Area = width * height
    print("Area of a Rectangle is: %.2f" %Area)
AreaofRectangle(8, 6)
```

Comment: Rectangular area only needs a simple multiplication, and there is no need for recursion.

Answer (score 3):

No, it isn't. The mentioned function simply calculates the area and prints it.

You can do it using recursion by adding the width again and again "height" number of times. See the example code below:

```
def AreaofRectangle(area,width, height):
    if height > 0 :
     area = area + width
     return AreaofRectangle(area,width,height-1)
    return area
area = AreaofRectangle(0, 8, 6)
print("Area of a Rectangle is: %.2f" %area)
```